# Confusion regarding Identity name in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

When I run the following code in my ASP.NET site which is running under an application pool with a pool identity of `Network Service`:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

I get the following value:

```
NT AUTHORITY\IUSR
```

Why does it shows `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` instead of `NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE`?

Now if I run `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()`, after that `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` shows the `NT AUTHORITY\\NETWORK SERVICE` value.

Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are you running the Application Pool in "Integrated" or "Classic" pipeline mode? 2. How have you configured your site's anonymous authentication (under `Authentication -> Anonymous Authentication`) ?

Comment: Sorry, two more questions: 3. What ASP.NET version are you running in the pool, v2.0 or v4.0? 4. What version of Windows and which service pack?